# How to have different heights between rows for each column?

Tags: html, css, grid, height, row

I've been using the bootstrap grid system and have encountered an issue where a taller div automatically sets the height for the entire row.

here is my problem:

http://prntscr.com/cf7cbh

this is a summary of my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row col-lg-4">small div</div>
    <div class="row col-lg-2">small div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">tall div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4">small div</div>
       <div class=" col-lg-2">small div</div>
       <div class="col-lg-6">tall div</div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

What can I do in order to have different heights? thank you